# How to use Eloquent column name out of with() block in laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, relation

I want to use eloquent column name out of with block.
I have tried `relationFunctionName.colun_name` and `tableName.column_name` but it gives me an error. no such column exists.


My query:

```
$d = FormsValues::select('forms_values.id', 'forms_values.patient_id','forms_values.doctor_id')
                    // ->with('getUserPatientAssinged')
                    ->with(array('getUserPatientAssinged' => function($query) use($user) {
                        $query
                        ->select('form_value_id','consultation_assigned_by','date as consultation_date', 'start_time as consultation_start_time', 'end_time as consultation_end_time','doctor_id')
                    }));
```

**--Some other code---**

```
$d = $d->where('getUserPatientAssinged.doctor_id', Auth::user()->id);
```

Any Solution?

Thank you

Comment: Using `->with()` doesn't make the columns available inside the query. You'd need to use `->join()` for that. Share the query you've tried please.

Comment: So it's not possible?

Comment: added the query in question.

Comment: I didn't say its not possible. Just add a `->join()` clause to join the table in the relationship, then you should be able to use `->where('joined_table.column')`. Keep the `->with()`; you can use both `->with()` and `->join()` in the same query.

Comment: Other then that no option. right?

Comment: You _might_ be able to use a `whereHas()` for this one, like `whereHas('getUserPatientAssinged.doctor', function($query){ $query->where('id', Auth::user()->id); })`. Basically, if the doctor of the patient is the current User. But I don't know your relationships and what not.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. If you can add it in the answer then I'll approve it. Thanks, again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you cannot use the columns of a relationship outside of a `->with()` clause unless you also use a `->join()`. For example:

```
FormsValues::with(['getUserPatientAssinged' => function ($query) { ... }])
->where('assigned_patients.doctor_id', auth()->user()->id)
->get();
```

Note: Assuming some table names, as you would reference that instead of the relationship name

The above code would likely throw an error around `assigned_patients.doctor_id` being an unknown column, as it is unavailable in the current scope. This can be solved by using a `->join()` along with the `->with()` clause:

```
FormsValues::with(['getUserPatientAssinged' => function ($query) { ... }])
->join('assigned_patients', ...)
->where('assigned_patients.doctor_id', ...)
->get();
```

Alternatively, we can use `->whereHas()` as long as the relationships are constructed. For this, we're looking for the `Doctor` of the "assigned patient", so:

```
FormsValues::with(['getUserPatientAssinged' => function ($query) { ... }])
->whereHas('getUserPatientAssigned.doctor', function ($query) {
  return $query->where('id', auth()->user()->id);
})->get();
```